# 'print key_1 + value_1+value_2 + good ' by using two dictionaries ?? nothing else

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
dic = {

    'key_1':['val_1','val_2'],
    'key_2':['val_3','val_4'],
    'key_3':['val_5','val_6']

}

info = {

    'i_1':'good',
    'i_2':'bad'

}

for k,v in dic.items()
    print 'Jack scrd'+info[i_2]+"in both subjects"+dic[val1]+'&'+dic[val2]
```

I know the print code is not right but gave it here for understanding what I really wanted to do here. I want only the above similar line in printing command.

Comment: What output are you expecting, exactly?

Comment: # Jack scrd bad in both subjects val_1 & val_2 . only this line i want to see don't want other lines.

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense, and this isn't a code-writing service. I'd suggest you put more effort in yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does this. The format command allows you to easily substitute `{}` with the variables of your choice in a string. When it comes to the dictionary `dic[k]` would render all the lists which `['val_1','val_2']` is one. So you would give `dic[k][0]` to get the first value, and `dic[k][1]` to get the second value.

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    msg = 'Jack scrd {} in both subjects {} & {}'
    print msg.format(info['i_2'], dic[k][0], dic[k][1])

# Jack scrd bad in both subjects val_1 & val_2
# Jack scrd bad in both subjects val_5 & val_6
# Jack scrd bad in both subjects val_3 & val_4
```

Comment: # Jack scrd bad in both subjects val_1 & val_2 . only this line i want to see don't want other lines.don't me wana use other values in output like it still printing 3 lines consist of all six values .. i just wanted to print 2 values on key_1 for jack

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do this?
Remove the for loop

```
print 'Jack scrd'+info['i_2']+'in both subjects'+str(dic['key_1'][0])+"&"+str(dic['key_1'][1])
```

Comment: # Jack scrd bad in both subjects val_1 & val_2 only this want to see don't want other lines

Comment: Akshay Apte don't me wana use other values in output like it still printing 3 lines consist  of all six values .. i just wanted to print 2 values on key_1 for jack

Comment: remove the for loop
 and add

`print 'Jack scrd'+info['i_2']+'in both subjects'+str(dic['key_1'][0])+"&"+str(dic['key_1'][1])`

Comment: yea first solution  was easy dude, i know that level python.. lol.. thank you for the later one. some times it is simple but we don't take easy ways.. blessings

Comment: haha yes. please upvote my answer if you found it helpful. :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use .join to join all list items with a given separator. If you want to print all keys of dic you can use:

```
dic = {

'key_1':['val_1','val_2'],
'key_2':['val_3','val_4'],
'key_3':['val_5','val_6']

}

info = {

'i_1':'good',
'i_2':'bad'

}

for keys in dic:
    # .join will join all list items for a particular key with & and store it in variable subjects
    subjects = ' & '.join(dic[keys])
    print "jack scored " + info['i_1'] + " in both subjects " + subjects
```

output:
    jack scored good in both subjects val_1 & val_2
    jack scored good in both subjects val_5 & val_6
    jack scored good in both subjects val_3 & val_4

Answer (score 0):

place_iraq = {

```
'shrine_1' : ['karbala','imam hussein as.'],
'shrine_2' : ['najaf', 'imam ali as.'],
'yard'   : ['karbala', 'wadi-us-salam'],
'shrine_3' : ['karbala', 'abbas as.']
```

}

type = {
    't1':'shrine',
    't2': 'grave yard'
}

print 'The '+str(type['t1'])+' of '+str(place_iraq['shrine_1'][1])+' is situated in ' +\
 str(place_iraq['shrine_1'][0])

print 'The '+str(type['t1'])+' of '+str(place_iraq['shrine_2'][1])+' is situated in ' +\
 str(place_iraq['shrine_2'][0])

print 'The '+str(type['t1'])+' of '+str(place_iraq['shrine_3'][1])+' is situated in ' +\
 str(place_iraq['shrine_3'][0])

print 'The '+str(type['t2'])+' of '+str(place_iraq['yard'][1])+' is situated in ' +\
 str(place_iraq['yard'][0])